# java.lang.NullPointerException: null error, with Graphics2D

Tags: graphics2d

I'm not a very good coder, but I am using Graphics2D in order to draw my tiles onto the screen, and everytime I compile, it would give me an error. I don't know why, as I am not a good coder, as I had >>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGGmxo5rcO4<< this video to tell me what I need to do. Yes, I am making 2048, but I seriously don't know what's wrong...

http://gyazo.com/9bd6d01ce9208c4836a1e2c39618266f
This is what happens when it would give me the error

Please let me know asap what I have done wrong! :c

Thanks!

Comment: I don't really see a question.

Comment: Looking at your screen shot, it appears that `tileImage` is null when you call `drawImage()`.